# how to remove xml configuration and filesets under tomcatserver 7 in mvc project?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I  want remove  xml configuration and filesets under server in spring mvc project.can any one help to me?.and it also show error like:

`HTTP Status 404 - /SpringIntegration/ description:The requested resource is not available.`

and it also show message like this in console:

```
tab.rg.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance 
in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;
C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;
C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;
Apr 04, 2017 11:22:29 AM org.apache.
```

and I attached a [Server Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeYVN.png).

Thanks:

Madhu

Answer (score 0):

when I run my mvc project I get this unsatisfied dependency 
 exception.Can any one find solution to this exception.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employ': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.empinterface.IEmploy' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}